# How to pass local arguments to "kpt fn render"?

Tags: kubernetes, kpt

I am trying to parameterize the `kpt fn render` pipeline.

I know that `kpt pkg get` automagically creates the `package-context.yaml` file containing a `ConfigMap` that in turn contains the name of the local kpt package. That is a good start, but what if I want to add additional local parameters to the pipeline between `kpt pkg get` and `kpt fn render`? Are there any best practices for this, or is this considered an anti-pattern for some reason?

Our current approach is to pass the parameters as environment variables, and the first step of the pipeline (a Starlark script) injects a `ConfigMap` with the parameters into the package. The rest of the pipeline steps refer to the fields of this "parameters" `ConfigMap`. Is there a better way?